# Errors while trying to import and format my own dataset in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, format, dataset

After successfully completing the tutorial with the clothes, I tried to use my own dataset (a folder containing subfolders representing the different types, and inside them the images of a given type.

My function returns a `(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels)` object where both part are split accordingly. Both "images" `list` contain the loaded and resized images and both "labels" `list` contain the labels of the corresponding indexes.

I think that the data structure returned by my function is identitical to the one returned by `keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()` used in the tutorial, and I'm pretty sure my function does a good job at building it. I also tried to print the images afterwards using `matplotlib.pyplot` and they look just fine. Even when I pass it a single training image and a single testing image with their corresponding labels both equal to 0 I keep having the same errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Rasp\project\main.py", line 72, in <module>
    ])
  File "C:\Users\axelc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1133, in fit
    data_handler = data_adapter.get_data_handler(
  File "C:\Users\axelc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1364, in get_data_handler
    return DataHandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\axelc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1152, in __init__
    adapter_cls = select_data_adapter(x, y)
  File "C:\Users\axelc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 991, in select_data_adapter
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"}), (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'int'>"})
```

I thought that maybe the `load_data()` function initialize things but I don't think so since it's a function given with a specific data set it seems like.

EDIT:

Here's my loading function:

```
def init_dataset(path, training_percent):
    dataset_folder = os.listdir(path)
    category_index = 0
    labels = []
    raw_dataset = []
    for category in dataset_folder:
        category_path = os.path.join(path, category)
        labels.append(category)
        raw_dataset.append([])
        for image in os.listdir(category_path):
            image_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(category_path, image), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            image_array = cv2.resize(image_array, (28, 28)) #TODO convolution & rotation instead of resize
            image_array = image_array / 255
            raw_dataset[category_index].append(image_array)
        print("Done loading " + category)
        category_index = category_index + 1
    train_images = []
    train_labels = []
    test_images = []
    test_labels = []
    categories_number = len(raw_dataset)
    for i in range(categories_number):
        category_total_images_number = len(raw_dataset[i])
        category_test_images_number = category_total_images_number - round(category_total_images_number * training_percent)
        for j in range(category_test_images_number):
            test_images.append(raw_dataset[i].pop(int(random.random() * len(raw_dataset[i]))))
            test_labels.append(i)
            print(i)
        for train_image in raw_dataset[i]:
            train_images.append(train_image)
            train_labels.append(i)
            print(i)
    dataset = {}
    dataset['labels'] = labels
    train_images = np.array(train_images).reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
    test_images = np.array(test_images).reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
    dataset['values'] = ((train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels))
    return dataset
```

And here's an example on how to use it:

```
dataset = init_dataset("C:/Rasp/DataSets/Dogs2", 0.8)
class_names = dataset['labels']
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = dataset['values']
```

Comment: "I think that the data structure returned by my function is identitical to the one returned by keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()". This is hard for people to check if that's the case without you sharing the code. A [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be appreciated.

Comment: You right, I'm editing right now.

Comment: Where exactly is line 72? It seems to be that you are passing in a list when it should be a numpy array but I cannot pinpoint where exactly.

Comment: It is here: `model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)`. Right before reading your answer I thought that this might be the problem and I still think it is, but I tried `train_images = np.array(train_images).reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)` and `test_images = np.array(test_images).reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)` at the end of my function but it had no effect whatsover (see my edit to see where I put it exactly).

Comment: What does `print(type(train_images))` and `print(type(train_labels))` return?

Comment: At first they are both `<class 'list'>` and after `np.array` they are both `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: you are doing a lot of work that you could avoid if you used ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory since your image data is store in directories based on the class. Use parameter validation_split then make a train_generator and test_generator using parameter subset in flow_from_directory.

Answer (score 0):

Pass an `numpy.array` to the fit function instead of an `array`.